# Angular: Population of Radio button groups in loop(ng-repeat) - selection not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to populate multiple groups of radio buttons in a loop and using a combination of group name and index for the name so as to uniquely group the radio buttons. The issue is - only the last group in the loop has the radio button checked. Other groups in the loop has nothing checked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - Dynamically populate Radio buttons in a loop</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="radioSetsExample">
  <script>
   angular.module('radioSetsExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.groups = [{
            name: 'group_one',
            type: 'CHOOSE'
        }, {
            name: 'group_two',
            type: 'ADD'
        },
        {
            name: 'group_three',
            type: 'ADD'
        }];
    }]);
</script>
 <form ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="group in groups">
        {{group.name}} - TYPE:
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="{{group.name}}_{{$index}}" value="CHOOSE" ng-model="group.type">
          Choose
        </label>
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="{{group.name}}_{{$index}}" value="ADD" ng-model="group.type">
          Add
        </label>
      </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MRoJDrc5PycIol87HnkW?p=preview)

Everything works fine if I manually give unique 'name' to each group in the loop and don't use index. But I cannot do that really since the list is going to be dynamic and there are no unique names. I have to depend on index to generate unique names to each group.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `name="{{group.name+'_'+$index}}"` instead of `name="{{group.name}}_{{$index}}"` then should wok fine.

```
<form ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="group in groups">
        {{group.name}} - TYPE:
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="{{group.name+'_'+$index}}" value="CHOOSE" ng-model="group.type">
          Choose
        </label>
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="{{group.name+'_'+$index}}" value="ADD" ng-model="group.type">
          Add
        </label>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes it work. Need to dig into expression syntax more. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome and glad to see that some one helped by me :)

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons require unique name property, what's happening currently is that the while iterating in the `ng-repeat`, first iteration gives the same name `group_one_1` to both Add and Choose radio.

Would this be possible:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="choose_{{$index}}" value="CHOOSE" ng-model="group.type">
      Choose
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="add_{{index}}" value="ADD" ng-model="group.type">
       Add
</label>
```

[Updated Working Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/nbhfj26UgZvJXQXsI6HM?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Dev-One..Thanks! But I can not really do that..i know that it will work if I remove the index - I am using index to derive unique 'name's to the groups - in the actual scenario i don't have unique names to each group. I am more interested in why using index is causing the issue.

Comment: That will break the grouping of radio buttons as they will have two different 'name's. Got the answer now. My expression syntax was wrong. Please refer to the other answer